# Bootstrap forms: some fixed width columns on grid system?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap forms and trying to get this kind of layout

| col-sm-4 | col-sm-2 having some fixed width column | col-sm-6 |

For the fixed width column I set the css like this

```
.fixed-width {
  min-width: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

That kindof work but I think it breaks the responsive behavior. Is there any idiomatic way to include fixed width element on the grid system of bootstrap?

Example: https://www.bootply.com/Qeq0BKqKlS#

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries.

Click [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to know what and how to use media queries.